# Css create space between words

Tags: html, css

I have a code that create buttons and also css for formatting them. I have moved these buttons to the right top side of the screen.Currently,they are side by side with each other but I want to create some space between each button and can't figure out which command to use in css to do it.

```css
.links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

li a {
  display: box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add margin-left: 5px; for example.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] with your current code? Also, fix the syntax errors like not closing your CSS selectors

Comment: `display:box`  ?? I think you meant `display:block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the surrounding html you can try this. I've changed some CSS to overwrite defaults (unordered list element) and also change some values to simplify what I think you want to achieve.

```html
<nav class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

For the css you should have `.links` as a parent selector so you don't target all list item links on the whole page.

```css
.links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.links ul {
  /* overwrite default styling */
  margin: 0;
  paddimg-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.links li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* next sibling selector */ 
.links li + li {
  margin-left: 1em; /* Target list items followed by a list item and add margin to the left of it */
}

.links a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nav class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

.links{
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  margin-top:-250px;
  margin-right:50px;
  z-index: 99;  
}

li { 
 margin-right: 5px
}

li a {
  display: box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can add some margin to the li elements